# $\cfrac{2x+3y}{a-2b} = \cfrac{4y+7z}{3b-c} = \cfrac{6z+5x}{2c-3a}$. Find, $11x+17y+20z$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

> $$\cfrac{2x+3y}{a-2b} = \cfrac{4y+7z}{3b-c} = \cfrac{6z+5x}{2c-3a}$$Find: $11x+17y+20z$

I tried to solve this through the normal and boring substitution method and the calculation is becoming extensively lengthy and ugly with $6$ variables.

Since this is an contest question (previous year's), I believe the examiners wouldn't make the students work so hard and consume so much time. So, I'd like to know if this question has a cleverer approach to it. I tried through componendo-dividendo too, but it doesn't seem to be working. I am not aware of matrices/determinants as of yet, so if the solution could be without the application of these, I'd be grateful. Thanks!

Comment: For a fixed set of choices for $a,b,c$ the system of equations describes a line $L$ through the origin in $\Bbb{R}^3$ (unless the system is degenerate in some way). For its part, the equation
$$11x+17y+20z=0$$ describes a plane $T$ through the origin. So if $L$ is a subset of $T$, then the answer will be constant zero. Otherwise $11x+17y+20z$ will take all the possible real values on $L$. With those preliminary considerations out of the way, I think I would know what to look for, and where to be careful.

Comment: At first sight the question seemed really terrible.  But it was very simple ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider them as vectors.

$$
\begin{cases}
\vec i = 2x + 3y \\
\vec j = 4y + 7z \\
\vec k = 6z + 5x \\
\vec v = 11x + 17y + 20z
\end{cases}
$$

Notice that they're orthogonal, so there's only one way for three scalars $A,B,C$ to satisfy the equation

$$ A\vec i + B\vec j + C\vec k = \vec v $$

That shouldn't be hard to figure out, right?

Now assign a "unit" to the equation:

$$ \cfrac{2x+3y}{a-2b} = \cfrac{4y+7z}{3b-c} = \cfrac{6z+5x}{2c-a} = \textbf{1} $$

Or

$$
\begin{cases}
\vec i = a - 2b \\
\vec j = 3b - c \\
\vec k = 2c - a
\end{cases}
$$

You can now know that

$$ \vec v = \textbf{1} \cdot 2a$$

---

Side note:

> Given how the coefficients for both *b* and *c* are zero, I have a feeling that the fraction part for the last fraction should be (2c-**3**a), making the final result a true zero.

Comment: AWESOME!! I never thought we could use vectors here. Thanks a lot, wonderful method.

Comment: Oh and btw, it is 3a, i actually messed up writing the question

Answer (score 2):

$t=\dfrac{6x+9y}{3a-6b} = \dfrac{8y+14z}{6b-2c} = \dfrac{5x+6z}{2c-a}= \dfrac{11x+17y+20z}{2a}\implies 11x+17y+20z = 2at$ .

**Note:** This answer is before OP's edit. Even after OP edited his question, the method still works. You just note that: $11x+17y+20z = 3(2x+3y)+ 2(4y+7z) + 6z+5x$.

Answer (score 1):

Let, $$\begin{align}&a≠2b, ~3b≠c, ~2c≠3a,~ m\in\mathbb R&\end{align} $$

Then, we have

$$\begin{align}\begin{cases} 2x+3y=m(a-2b) \\ 4y+7z =m(3b-c) \\ 6z+5x=m(2c-3a) \end{cases} \\ \\ \iff \begin{cases} 6x+9y=3m(a-2b) \\ 8y+14z =2m(3b-c) \\ 6z+5x=m(2c-3a) \end{cases} \end{align}$$

$$\begin{align} &11x+17y+20z=m(3a-6b+6b-2c+2c-3a)=0.&\end{align} $$